# how to re-use react callback for lifting state up?

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand how to abstract my callback function that is passed to the instances of my child component as a prop to lift state up to the parent component:

```
/* Parent */

typeCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    var filter = {...this.state.filter}
    filter.type = dataFromChild;
    this.setState({filter}, () => console.log(this.state));
}

makeCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    var filter = {...this.state.filter}
    filter.make = dataFromChild;
    this.setState({filter}, () => console.log(this.state));
}

...

/* Parent render() */

<Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_type' placeholder='Type' parentCallback={this.typeCallback}/>
<Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_make' placeholder='Make' parentCallback={this.makeCallback}/>
```

I would like to abstract my callback function to take in the name of the state variable of the parent that it should update. At the moment I have 6 instances of Child component and 6 corresponding copies of callback function tailored to update the target state variable (i.e. this.state.filter.type, this.state.filter.make)

```
/* Child */

handleSelectorValueCreate = () => {
    fetch(this.props.url, {
                            method:  'POST',
                            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                            body:    val,
                          })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {  this.setState({value: response}, () => this.sendData() ); })


sendData = () => {
    this.props.parentCallback(this.state.value);
}

/* Child render() */

<Child onChange={this.handleSelectorValueChange} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could extend parent's prop of function's arguments to do this

```
/* Parent */
commonCallback = (dataFromChild, type) => {
  var filter = { ...this.state.filter };
  filter[type] = dataFromChild;
  this.setState({ filter }, () => console.log(this.state));
};

....
<Child
   url="http://localhost:5000/device_type"
   placeholder="Type"
   parentCallback={liftState => {
    /* Use type as second parameter for differentiating*/
    this.commonCallback(liftState, 'type');
   }}
/>
```

This creates common callback with two parameters - `stateToLift` and `type`.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that the callback (probably  a handler) is re created every time and causes React to do DOM re render where none are needed. Just do `parentCallback={commonCallback} callbackKey="type"` and in child: `onSometing={()=>props.parentCallback(value,props.callbackKey)}`. You can wrap that in a useCallback or make Child a pure component by extending React.PureComponent or wrapping it in React.memo for function components.

Comment: Oh, this is more effective version. I did it in a naive way. Thanks for flagging.

Comment: I added an answer with optimized versions using React.memo (could also be pure component). Or if OP can't change Child then use useCallback in a container.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to pass a callback to a child is to pass something that won't change each render because the callback is likely to be used as a handler and will cause React to needlessly do DOM re renders.

So it's best to just pass a function and have that function receive both key and value:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
  }
  parentCallback = (data, key) => {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    items[key] = data + 1;
    this.setState({ items });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.items.map((val, index) => (
          <Child
            key={index} //never use index in key where you can re sort or re arrange items
            parentCallback={this.parentCallback}
            callbackKey={index}
            val={val}
          />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const Child = React.memo(function Child({
  parentCallback,
  callbackKey,
  val,
}) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => parentCallback(val, callbackKey)}
      >
        {val}
      </button>
      <div>Rendered: {rendered.current} times.</div>
    </div>
  );
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you cannot change the Child component then you can create a container for it and use useCallback:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
  }
  parentCallback = (data, key) => {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    items[key] = data + 1;
    this.setState({ items });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.items.map((val, index) => (
          <ChildContainer
            key={index} //never use index in key where you can re sort or re arrange items
            parentCallback={this.parentCallback}
            callbackKey={index}
            val={val}
          />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const ChildContainer = ({
  parentCallback,
  callbackKey,
  val,
}) => {
  const newCallback = React.useCallback(
    () => parentCallback(val, callbackKey),
    [parentCallback, val, callbackKey]
  );
  return <Child parentCallback={newCallback} val={val} />;
};
const Child = React.memo(function Child({
  parentCallback,
  val,
}) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={parentCallback}>{val}</button>
      <div>Rendered: {rendered.current} times.</div>
    </div>
  );
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Meet Zaveri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7121483/meet-zaveri) and [HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr) for the solution!

```
/* Parent */

commonCallback = (dataFromChild, key) => {
  var filter = { ...this.state.filter };
  filter[key] = dataFromChild;
  this.setState({ filter }, () => console.log(this.state.filter));
};

/* Parent render() */

<Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_type' placeholder='Type'
       parentCallback={this.commonCallback} callbackKey="type"/>
<Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_make' placeholder='Make'
       parentCallback={this.commonCallback} callbackKey="make"/>


/* Child */

sendData = () => {
  this.props.parentCallback(this.state.value, this.props.callbackKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

**Parent Component**

```
  handleFilter = field => childData => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      filter: {
        ...prevState.filter,
        [field]: childData
      }
    }, () => console.log(this.state));
  }

  ...

  <Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_type' placeholder='Type' handleFilter={this.handleFilter("type")}/>
  <Child url='http://localhost:5000/device_make' placeholder='Make' handleFilter={this.handleFilter("make")}/>
```

Explanation:
From this way, I use [currying](https://medium.com/swlh/currying-and-function-composition-in-javascript-356041d8e2b4) to pass a field will indicate to you which field is going to be updated and I use setState method with prevState directly which will prevent you from not following [inmutability rule in react class components](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/#what-is-immutability).

PD: and I imagine you'll be able to render the kids with a map function and give them the properties you need.

Comment: Disadvantage if this solution is that you will cause unneeded DOM re renders because the callback function (likely a handler) will be re created every time so even virtual dom compare will fail and React will re render each Child even though nothing changed.

Comment: Curious, why do you think (although React is usually quite optimized in terms of re-rendered) that should pass as callback the state and within it call the function with the state itself and the type to perform the method I have inside?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for introducing me to currying. I am however getting a parsing error (unexpected token) in const declaration. I am declaring `const handleFilter` within the parent component

Comment: @fg93 I added an answer, where do you think useCallback is used for? If I have a button: `<Button onClick={props.callback} />` and use it like `<Button onClick={()=>new ref every time}` then React will perform a most expensive operation (DOM re render), if you have hundreds of these buttons then this is not a good situation. Even `<Child data={{name:'Ben',age:22}}` could possibly be caught by React virtual DOM compare but it's best to not pass new references as props to children on every render, especially callbacks.

Comment: Sorry @soundust I was creating a function inside FComponent hahaha. It's without "const"